# Swift alert not performing action

Tags: swift

I have an application that is showing an alert for incomplete input as shown:

```
if (foodChosen == "") {
            let alertAction = UIAlertController(title: "Continue?", message: "No food selected. Do you wish to continue?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.finish = true
            })
            alertAction.addAction(yes)
            let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            })
            alertAction.addAction(no)
            self.present(alertAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.finish = true
        }
```

where `self.finish` is initialised to `false` at the beginning of the view controller.

Even when selecting the "Yes" button, the value of self.finish is never updated. Can anyone see why?

Comment: How do you determine that `finish` is not updated?

Comment: @vadian I happened to be debugging the section after

Comment: Can you add a `print` statement inside the handler for your `yes` action to verify it's actually being called? If so, also print out the value of your `finish` boolean before the action is presented and after the handler is called just to see if its getting changed. I'm curious to hear what happens. Also if I were you I'd change the style for your `no` action from `.default` to `.cancel`.

Comment: @Pierce, it appears the issue is that the check of the value of `finish` underneath is being executed before the result of the alert is checked. I assume there's a better way than having a new variable to hold the state of the alert and then busy waiting until it is set

Comment: @BenDent - It sounds to me like you're leaving out some crucial details here - like what you're using this `finish` boolean for and where? If you have some method or chunk of code that executes only if `finish == true`, but it's being called at the same time that your action is presented, then even once they tap yes it won't fire because you need to call it again AFTER it's changed. Try copying whatever code you have for `if finish { do this }` inside the handler for your `yes` action underneath where you say `self.finish = true`.

Comment: Thanks, @Pierce, I just moved everything inside the body of the check into another function and called that within the alert action. No need for `finish` now!

Comment: @BenDent - No problem.